# How to show different message is log in one single row

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

I have a sql code in which I have different files and I am loading them in DB.

My query is can we log all error message and show them in logs with ELSE if condition

below is my code

```
IF @var=1
BEGIN 
IF NOT EXISTS(condition)
BEGIN
Error message
Set @var2=1
END
ELSE IF
IF Not EXISTS(condition)
BEGIN
Error message
Set @var2=1
END
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(condition)
BEGIN
Error message
Set @var2=1
END
END
If(@var2=1)
BEGIN
insert into log
RETURN
END
```

Now what it is doing it is checking if first is mission it will log a error message and return. what I want is if it not match all the condition in IF else then it will log all error message.

Can you guys guide me with this. Can I concatenate error message in one and log them and how. Any help in this.

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare variable on top like on my code and concatenate it every time you expected an error message.

I assume in your sample code line the 'Error message' will show on that code line.

```
DECLARE @ERRORMESSAGE AS varchar(255)


IF @var=1
   BEGIN 
       IF NOT EXISTS(condition)
       BEGIN
         Error message
          Set @var2=1
       END
       IF Not EXISTS(condition)
       BEGIN
         Error message
         Set @var2=1
       END
       IF NOT EXISTS(condition)
       BEGIN
          Error message
          Set @var2=1
       END

 END


If(@var2=1)
BEGIN
insert into log
RETURN
END
```

Comment: you can add 'return' to end I will update my answer

Comment: it is showing NULL in the log if first file is loaded and 2 and 3 rd is not available

Comment: Yes maybe because the first condition was satisfied and it will not going to other condition because your using ELSE IF, Try to use IF only in all conditions so the sql will scan/run each conditions.

Comment: i want Return at the end of all so that it will check which file is available and then log message

Comment: @Amitesh cool! I indent it properly and replace else if to if :)

Comment: don't update it i just change else if to if and it work